# Can I use an ANOVA calculation when considering the total amount of right answers?

Tags: anova, mean

I have been conducting an experiment about hyper-reality audio in football. The experiment comprises two experimental groups. One control group sees 9 football video clips with only the sound of the crowd. The treatment group sees the same video clips with the sound of the crowd + the sound of the ball being kicked. I am asking 18 polar questions regarding the video clips to each group, in order to see if the sound of the ball can improve accuracy. At the end of the experiment I am summing all the right answers for each participant and comparing the two group means. Can I use a one-way ANOVA in this situation?

Thanks for your help!

Alberto

Comment: With only two groups ANOVA corresponds to the two sample t-test with equal variances. So you can do many things: two sample t-test, two sample Wilcoxon test, two sample permutation test on either mean of median etc.